# How to do Parallel operations with Thread Scope in Web app using Ninject

Tags: dependency-injection, task-parallel-library, ninject

I've run into the same question repeatedly whenever using a new DI framework... how do you run massively-parallel operation kicked off from an HttpRequest where each thread needs its own unique copy of the dependencies?  In my case, I'm using Ninject.

The specific case I always run into is a CPU-intensive report, using Parallel.ForEach, that needs to use an Entity Framework DbContext; the EF context must be unique to the thread, but outside of these special reports the EF context it must be InRequestScope.

How do you achieve this with Ninject?  Preferably allow disposing the EF context with each task on the Parallel.ForEach, since the data loaded with the context would just stay in the context and consume memory.

Note that this report is big enough to warrant Parallel.ForEach but small enough that it can run synchronously on a web request and not timeout the browser (<60 seconds).  Maybe I'm weird, but I run into this need **a lot**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution has several different moving parts that, IMO, aren't terribly well-documented parts of Ninject.  The upside is that after implementing something like this, you should start feeling comfortable with Ninject *in a hurry!*

First, you need to change the scope for your objects so they use the HttpContext if it exists, and if not, use the current thread as a fallback.  There is no documentation for this, but there is a DefaultScopeCallback that was added to the settings a while back.  Set that property to your own scope callback which uses the same code in the [Ninject.Web.Common source](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Web.Common/blob/master/src/Ninject.Web.Common/RequestScopeExtensionMethod.cs) to get the HttpContext, but then use "?? Thread.CurrentThread" as the fallback.  Do that in the CreateKernel code that should have been created automatically when you installed the NuGet package.

(I have substituted the StandardScopeCallbacks.Thread(ctx) where I used to have Thread.CurrentThread, since the former could conceivably change at some point.  Currently those two are identical in what they do.)

```
private static IKernel CreateKernel()
{
    var settings = new NinjectSettings{ DefaultScopeCallback = DefaultScopeCallback };
    var kernel = new StandardKernel(settings);
    // The rest of the default implementation of CreateKernel left out for brevity
}

private static Object DefaultScopeCallback(Ninject.Activation.IContext ctx)
{
    var scope = ctx.Kernel.Components.GetAll<INinjectHttpApplicationPlugin>()
        .Select(c => c.GetRequestScope(ctx)).FirstOrDefault(s => s != null);
    return scope ?? Ninject.Infrastructure.StandardScopeCallbacks.Thread(ctx);
}
```

Also, don't forget that the Kernel needs to be set aside as a static object for access later.  You don't want to new-up a new Kernel every time you need it; I make mine accessible via "MyConfig.ObjectFactory".  While this is a code smell of the service locator anti-pattern, we're going to great lengths here to avoid the anti-pattern as much as possible.

Second, according to the commit description, the DefaultScopeCallback only affects explicit bindings with no explicit scope.  So if, like me, you were depending on a bunch of implicit bindings that you hadn't added, you now need to configure them:

```
kernel.Bind(i => i.From(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(), Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Bll.MyConfig)))
    .SelectAllClasses()
    .BindToSelf());
```

If you don't like doing the above, there's another way of setting the default scope for all implicit bindings that is arguably more elegant.  [Changing default object scope with Ninject 2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438123/changing-default-object-scope-with-ninject-2-2)

Third, if you'd like to clear all cached objects from the scope at the end of each Parallel operation so that memory usage doesn't skyrocket due to EF caching or whatnot, here's how clear the Ninject cache scoped to the current thread:

```
Parallel.ForEach(myList, i =>
{
    var threadDb = MyConfig.ObjectFactory.Get<MyContext>();
    CreateModelsForItem(i, threadDb);
    MyConfig.ObjectFactory.Components.Get<Ninject.Activation.Caching.ICache>().Clear(Thread.CurrentThread);
});
```

Note that I did some testing without that Clear line at the end, and it seemed like the EF Context was getting re-used even if that HttpRequest finished and I generated the report several more times.  This was not what I wanted, so the Clear operation was important.  Really, the behavior I want is closer to InCallScope, but trying to get InRequestScope with InCallScope as a fallback is a can of worms I'll open on another day.